# How to extend a line series as dotted only when checkbox is clicked?

Tags: highcharts

I have a line series from say 0-t1 interval of x.
i want to show an extended dashed line from t1-t2(in the same series) if user click on the checkup next to legend.

Can anyone suggest how to go about it?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should be able to use zones for changing dashStyle in your series: http://jsfiddle.net/yavvLvea/

Comment: Ya I saw that, but my requirement is a bit different, I don't want the dashed line to be shown at the first place, it shud only come up when users like a check up next to the series legend name

Comment: It is possible to update series dynamically in HC. http://jsfiddle.net/yavvLvea/1/ If my example will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: Wow, Yes please, just a little change, on check box click  new data will come ( which is prediction data) and the line will extend as as dotted to accommodate the new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use checkboxClick function for updating your series on checkbox click:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.checkboxClick
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update

You can use zones for changing style of your line from some value:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.zones

```
  series: [{
    data: [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 10, 10, 5, 0, -5],
    showCheckbox: true,
    events: {
      checkboxClick: function() {
        var checkbox = this.checkbox;
        var newData = $.extend([], true, data);
        for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
          newData.push(20 * Math.random());
        }
        if (checkbox.checked) {
          this.update({
            zones: [{
              value: data.length - 1,
            }, {
              dashStyle: 'dash'

            }],
            selected: false,
            zoneAxis: 'x',
            data: newData
          })
        } else {
          this.update({
            zones: [],
            data: data,
            selected: true
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }]
```

Live example of a chart with zones:
http://jsfiddle.net/yavvLvea/3/